# How to write type hints when you change type of a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

Say that I have

```
def foo(x: Union[str, list[str]], y: Union[str, list[str]]) -> tuple[list[str], list[str]]:
     
    x = cast(Union[list[str], tuple[list[str], ...]], str2list(x))  
    y = cast(Union[list[str], tuple[list[str], ...]], str2list(y))  
    
    return x,y
     
def str2list(*args: Union[str, list[str]]) -> Union[list[str], tuple[list[str], ...]]:
    vals = []
    for x in args:
        if not isinstance(x, list):
            x = [x]
        vals.append(x)
    if len(args) == 1:
        return vals[0]
    else:
        return tuple(vals)
    

x = 'My name is x'
y = ['First element', 'Second element']

z = str2list(x,y)
```

As you see, there are two `cast` calls in `foo`, but still `mypy` complains that

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[List[str], Tuple[List[str], ...]]", variable has type "Union[str, List[str]]")  [assignment]
```

A workaround could be to define new variables and adjust the return type of foo as it follows

```
def foo(
    x: Union[str, list[str]], y: Union[str, list[str]]
) -> tuple[
    Union[list[str], tuple[list[str], ...]],
    Union[list[str], tuple[list[str], ...]],
]:

    xl = cast(Union[list[str], tuple[list[str], ...]], str2list(x))
    yl = cast(Union[list[str], tuple[list[str], ...]], str2list(y))

    return xl, yl
```

But I would prefer to overwrite `x` and `y` rather than defining two new variables `xl` and `yl`.

Comment: Mypy is a static type checker, but changing the type of a variable is a dynamic type behavior, so mypy will not allow it anyway.

Comment: I think that `mypy` allows it: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_narrowing.html#casts

Comment: Casting from parent class to child class is also supported in static type languages, but your current code obviously has nothing to do with it. In a statically typed language, you cannot convert a string into a string list and assign it to the original object.

Comment: Ok, so that means that I must define a new object, necessarily?

Comment: In general, yes, but it is not necessary in this example, you can return them directly.

Comment: For constructs like `x = f(x)` which are absolute (not belonging to conditional branch, but executed always) mypy allows redefinition with `--allow-redefinition` flag (and corresponding config entry), which is often useful. Seems like it's your case.

Comment: Many thanks! I see a philosophical question here: I like to see as little variables as possible in my code because it allows me to better follow the logic flow, but from a robustness point of view, redefining variables (especially when using casting operators that implies a different size/representation in memory) is not really the best thing to. Wrong reasoning?